Let's get critical: Feb 2015 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

CIR model: is the short rate really non-central $\chi^2$ distributed?

Net Score: 6 (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)


When are implied and real world parameters the same?

Net Score: 5 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)


Deriving the definition of stochastic integrals with respect to Ito processes from first principles

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)


Some questions about implied volatilities and how to generate theoretical prices when market prices are not available

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)


Why is there onshore and offshore currency?

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)


Black Scholes formula with continuous dividend paying stock

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)


How to obtain a log of all trades done on the Nasdaq or other major US exchange?

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)


Is printing money really a bad thing?

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)


How to compute the VaR for European Call, using the delta-normal method?

Net Score: -2 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)


How to get Multivariate Betas from an Estimated EWMA co variance Matrix?

Net Score: -4 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 5)


As someone who is just getting into the world of Finance in general, I often find the language in both questions and answers to be very high-context, and this has persistently been the major obstacle which prevents me from participating more.

Hi André Terra, I don't necessarily see that as a problem, also see our [faq] but I'm curious about which questions and answers you mean.Can you give any concete examples?
